# render html text to bitmap using javascript without serverSide code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i need to use a javascript code to convert the articles, posts in html to be viewed to the end user as a bitmap, is there any way to do it, without server side code?

example:

```
<p> testing text here .... </p>
```

Comment: Why? so people that have poor eyesight cannot access your page?

Comment: You could use a canvas, of course, but yeah, I would do that on the server side.

Comment: it is a requirement, i have no choice !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert your page to bitmap.

If your HTML does not contain any external references you can also use my following function:

```
/**
 *    Canvas extension: drawHTMLText(txt, options)
 *    By Ken Nilsen, Epistemex
 *    http://epistemex.com/
 *
 *    USAGE:
 *        myContext.drawHTMLText(txt [, options]);
 *
 *    var options = {x: startPosition,
 *                   y: startPosition,
 *                   width: maxWidth,
 *                   height: maxHeight,
 *                   callback: myFunction,
 *                   callbackError: myErrorFunction}
 *
 *    Each individual option is optional in themself. The callback
 *    on success contains an object with reference to result and
 *    originalText. Error callback is provided with the error object.
 *
 *    License: MIT
 */

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawHTMLText = function(txt, options) {

    /// make sure we have an object if none was provided
    options = options || {};

    var ctx = this,

        /// build inline SVG
        iSVG =

        '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' +
        (options.width ? options.width : ctx.canvas.width) +

        '" height="' +
        (options.height ? options.height : ctx.canvas.height) +
        '"><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +

        '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font:' +
        ctx.font + ';color:' + ctx.fillStyle + '">' +

        txt +

        "</div></foreignObject></svg>",

        /// create Blob of inlined SVG
        svg = new Blob([iSVG],{type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),

        /// create URL (handle prefixed version)
        domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
        url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg),

        /// create Image
        img = new Image;

    /// handle image loading
    img.onload = function () {

        /// draw SVG to canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img,
                      (options.x ? options.x : 0),
                      (options.y ? options.y : 0));

        domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        /// invoke callback if provided
        if (typeof options.callback === 'function')
            options.callback({result: img,
                              originalText: txt});
    };

    /// handle potential errors
    img.onerror = function(e) {
        if (typeof options.callbackError === 'function') {
            options.callbackError(e);
        } else {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    img.src = url;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 800;  /// size of your resulting bitmap
canvas.height = 600;

ctx.drawHTMLText(...html here...);

var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL();
```

`dataUri` now contains the bitmap encoded as a data-uri (which is in string format). This string can be sent to server or set as `href` on an anchor tag together with a download attribute:

```
<a id="downloadLink">Click here to download</a>
```

From JS:

```
/// obtain dataUri here
downloadLink.href = dataUri;
downloadLink.download = 'filename.png';
```

Important: The HTML code you want to draw must not contain any external references (CSS, images etc.) as the *browser* will restrict the SVG from being drawn as an image to canvas due to security reasons.