# I am trying to create a table that can be resizable and moveable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a table that can be edited, resized and moved on canvas. I used the following code for creating a table on canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    setColumn = document.getElementById("column"),
    setRow = document.getElementById("row"),
    btnGen = document.getElementById("btnGen"),
    copy = document.getElementById("copy"),
    nOfColumns = -1,
    nOfRows = -1;

function generateTable(e) {
    var a = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var b = e.pageY - canvas.offsetRight;
    var newTable = document.getElementById("mytable");
    tBody = newTable.createTBody();
    nOfColumns = parseInt(setColumn.value, 10);
    nOfRows = parseInt(setRow.value, 10);
    context.fillText(appendRows(tBody), canMouseX, canMouseY);
}

function createTable() {
    canvas.onmousedown = generateTable;
}

function appendColumns(tElement, count) {
    var cell = null,
        indexOfRow = [].indexOf.call(tElement.parentNode.rows, tElement) + 1,
        indexOfColumn = -1;
    count = count || nOfColumns;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cell = tElement.insertCell(i);
        indexOfColumn = [].indexOf.call(tElement.cells, cell) + 1;
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "text";
        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
}

function appendRows(tElement, count) {
    var row = null;
    count = count || nOfRows;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        row = tElement.insertRow(i);
        appendColumns(row);
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "text";
        row.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

When I am clicking on the canvas the table is getting generated below the canvas not on the canvas and one extra row and column are getting created. Even I want to resize and move the above generated table on the canvas. whether it is possible to do so.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place any DOM elements inside Canvas tags, or embed them for that matter so they become part of the bitmap. Canvas is just that, a bitmap which you can only draw to using JavaScript and the supported draw operations on its context.

If you want tables I would suggest you use regular HTML. Anything between canvas open and close tag is ignored by browsers which support canvas.

There are ways to draw DOM elements onto a canvas element using SVG as a wrapper but it comes with certain limitations related to security (ie. external references).

If table is all you want them ignore the canvas bit in this.

If you really want to draw HTML tables onto canvas you can do it two ways:

1. Emulate the layout and look of tables by manually drawing every line, header, text, cell and so on.
2. Use the above mentioned SVG approach to convert DOM elements into a SVG image which you then draw to canvas (in case you want to save a snapshot of the table as an image). Please see my earlier answer about this here: [render html text to bitmap using javascript without serverSide code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214620/render-html-text-to-bitmap-using-javascript-without-serverside-code/21214806#21214806)